# How do I prevent overwriting the name of a saved image, if the previously saved image was deleted?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

```
Dim data As IDataObject
    Dim bmap As Image
    SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY, 0, 0)
    data = Clipboard.GetDataObject
    If data.GetDataPresent(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)) Then
        bmap = CType(data.GetData(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)), Image)
        PictureBox1.Image = bmap
        SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, iDevice, 0)
        DestroyWindow(hHwnd)
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim counter = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\Data\Image")
        Dim intCount As Integer
        Dim strfilename As String
        intCount = CStr(counter.Count)
        strfilename = "Image" & intCount + 1
        PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\Data\Image\" & strfilename & ".jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Dim strpath As String = "C:\Data\Image\" & strfilename & ".jpeg"
        Label1.Text = strpath
    End If
```

the name of the image that the image is stored in. image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8 and so on. if any image with the name image4 is deleted then the image file to be saved will look for the name with the largest number and then add 1

Comment: You can probably just store the image counter as a Field or a class Property, so you won't reset it every time and you most probably need to call `GetFiles()` just once, to initialize this Field or Property to the maximum value you find + 1. Possibly, format this value as, e.g., `0001`, `0100`  instead of `1`,  `100` before appending it to the file name: it's easier to parse.

Comment: Are you going to have to remember the next image number between sessions or only while the app is running?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to go to "**My Project**" => "**Settings**" and create "**intCounter**" as an integer. (Do not change the value)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iGyI.png

Every time an image is saved the intCounter should increase by 1. This can be done by:  `Remote.My.Settings.intCounter = Remote.My.Settings.intCounter + 1`

`strfilename = "Image" & Remote.My.Settings.intCounter`

If the program is closed, the value of intCounter will be kept.